# How can I fix images appearing stretched?

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer

So I just put up a website for my high school and realized a lot of images are stretched especially on this page
[www.eriesd.org/central/central2/staff.php](http://www.eriesd.org/central/central2/staff.php)

What you be the best way to make the images not so stretched?

I was thinking of adding a div and adding background image with center center or 50% 50%. Also on the career and tech pages I noticed the info page doesn't load in IE but the other pages load fine has anyone else ever had this problem?

I'm basically getting the location in menu and option and calling an ajax request which loads 1 of the 3 layouts which connects to my database and gets information depending on the option and location.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question at a time.

Comment: also try and pick better titles

Comment: from your comment about an image resizer: you can also calculate and emit image sizes dynamically using the php GD calls

Comment: @horatio Yeah I do and and the image type as well as name I also allow you to save an image in a selected directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the pictures are uploaded using some kind of php CMS, the first thing I would do, is process the images correctly at the moment they are uploaded: Apart from the bigger image, you would need to generate a thumbnail that fits the size you need for that page.

I would also recommend adding a notice to people who are uploading a picture, that this specific picture needs to have a landscape format as that is what you are using on the page.

CSS solutions would be my last resort to iron out small issues.

**Edit:** Apart from that I would seriously reconsider publishing all e-mail addresses like that and add some pagination as the page now takes a long time to load (especially with all the images being a lot bigger than you need them to be...).

Comment: Yes, I built a small cms since they didn't need that many options. I actually coded an image resizer too so ill just try using that and eliminated the inline width and height styling

Comment: What do you mean publishing emails like that? Teacher recommended using images because someone can easily write something to grab all emails on the page or are you talking about making it a mailto link?

Comment: @josh All e-mails appear in the source code as plain text so any spammer can scan your page for these addresses very easily. Using images is a solution, but there are others, just check here on SO.

Comment: alright already found an algorithm for encrypting them was gonna use javascript at first but if someone doesn't have javascript enable they can easily see the email by viewing the source. Still working on resizing the images was trying to use a photoshop script that resized all images in a folder and saved them to another but I'm not sure how well that's going to work

Answer (score 3):

They are stretched because you specified both `width` and `height` attributes for the `<img>` tag. If the actual image is of different dimensions, one can see how the browser has no options but to distort the image to make it fit the specified height and width.

Just don't specify either `height`, or `width`, or both, and the images are going to be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `height` only on the img and add the `width:200px;text-align:center` CSS to the `anchor` if you want the white area either side. Omitting the width will shrink the whitespace around the image.

```
<a class="image" style="width:200px;text-align:center">
    <img src="http://www.eriesd.org/central/central2/images/staff/kranking.jpg" alt="missing photo" height="112">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your first question concerning images.  The real problem is that your images are not sized to fit the space you want them to fill.  One of them that I inspected was a 6MP (2848x2144) image weighing in at 1.5MB.  There were many more of this approximate size and dimensin.  Any one of those images is larger than the entire page should be by quite a lot.  The first step is getting images to the size you need them to be.  Your page is nearly 19MB.  Not only so most browsers do a lousy job of scaling images, you're sending a ton of extra data and making the page load very slowly for users without very fast connections.  Imagine a user with a mobile browser waiting on this and chewing through their data plan!  A user with DSL might need several minutes; dial-up could require hours.

If you're uploading them manually, resize them first.  Figure out a size constraint and resize and crop first.  If you're using a CMS, find settings, plugins, or customize it to make a smaller thumbnail version and use it.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the layout looking nice and equal, the only thing you can do is either stretch them as it is now, or, even better, crop the images a bit and resize them.  You can probably do it programmatically for most of the pictures, just assume that the top center is where their head will be.  You have stretched picture issues all over the site though.

As for the Career & Tech pages, they're still actually being loaded (at least in the latest IE) if you look at the source, but they're not being shown for some reason, so, either you have some CSS or JavaScript issues with .post or .content.  It even pops up for a second sometimes and then disappears.

Comment: LYeah I noticed it will show for a second and disappear ill have to checkout it out later and see exactly what is going on

Answer (score 0):

If you specify only a width, the height will be set proportionally and thus prevent stretching of your images.